# Duda con Excepciones en java

Tags: java

Me dijeron que es de malas practicas usar excepciones del tipo runtimeexception y sus subclases porque si ocurre algun error de este tipo se puede solucionar mejorando la logica de programacion sin usar estas excepciones.Ahora yo tengo un problema.Cuando Tengo un programa que por consola se pide un numero,el problema esta cuando en vez de un numero se ingresa un String.Se lanza una excepcion de tipo NumberFormatException,se puede de alguna forma implementar algun codigo que solucione esto sin usar excepciones.
Y es cierto esto de que es de malas practicas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es importante tener claro que son las Excepciones y para que sirven, y si la lógica de tu programa reclama una excepción no la debes evitar.

En tu ejemplo, si te entra un error y no quieres implementar Excepciones puedes ayudarte del código asci (en este ejemplo y seguro que hay más soluciones) con "IF" "ELSE".

Pero si pensamos un poco, es lógico que se genere una Excepcion ya que tu programa espera un número y no un String. Si por ejemplo utilizas la classe Scanner para leer un int :

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.In);
int numeroLeido=sc.nextInt() //lee el número introducido por teclado.
```

En este ejemplo que te he puesto, nuestro programa intenta leer una variable que va a ser entrada por teclado de tipo "Int". Pero si le entramos un "char" o un "String", hay un problema de lógica de nuestro programa ya que estamos intentando guardar un "char" o un "String" en una variable que hemos declarado como Int, y esto es un error de lógica de nuestro programa.

Por consecuencia, esto genera una Excepcion, ya que en nuestra variable numeroLeido se esperaba un int, y se ha intentado guardar otro dato que no es un Int.

Y respondiendo a la pregunta de RunTimeException, se dice esto porque este tipo de ejecuciones no se puede recuperar el error, en cambio por ejemplo las Excepciones como IOExcepcion sí.

Espero haber podido ayudarte.

Answer (score 1):

No sé si considerar como "mala practica" el uso de excepciones. Más que nada por que en ciertas ocasiones son inevitables. Lo que te habrán dicho de Runtime es por que, al implementar una superclase de excepción no sabes exactamente ¿por que? se esta ejecutando la excepción. Pudiendo llegara  incumplir o fallar en puntos externos al que pusiste la excepción.

Generalmente pro lo mismo siempre intento usar la clase de menor jerarquía cuando necesito reaccionara  un posible error. Aunque tampoco habría nada de malo en hacer un catch a exception...al final del día solo te perjudicaría a vos.

Sobre si es posible el evitar esto, creo que existe una pregunta que te podría servir:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093326/restricting-jtextfield-input-to-integers

igualmente, y a riesgo de equivocarme, probablemente el IDE te fuerce a hacer el catch igual.

Espero haberte ayudado c:

Comment: Si,es verdad eso de usar la clase de menor jerarquia.al usar una de mayor se estaria haciendo generica la respuesta,si se necesita descubrir puntualmente cual es el error se tendria que usar la de menor.Gracias amigo

Answer (score 1):

A mi me parece buena idea reacoger los inputs del usuario con **nextLine()**, y asi le pasas unos checks y compruebas que no sea nulo, integer o el tipo que tu quieras,ya que puedes capturar las excepciones igualmente, pero es más flexible.